# How to get response from HttpURLConnection POST

Tags: java

I am trying to send a POST (with XML in the body) to an API and get a response back that is XML. There are confirmation or error details that I need to get from the response body (from within the `ERROR`element).

I can send the POST and it does trigger the change in the API, but I cannot read the response.

When I send the POST manually from Postman, I trigger the change in the API and I can see the response from the API as `text/html;charset=charset=utf-8`

Here is my current code:

```
      URL url = new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(xmlString);
        writer.flush();
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
```

The response body should be in the following format:

```
<Root>
    <Session>
        <UserId>theUserID</UserId>
        <Password>thePassword</Password>
        <ERROR Status="0" Description="Logon Successful" />
    </Session>
    <ActivityList>
        <Activity Type="ReqUp" Incident="12345" ElapsedTime="350" 
      Description="example response" 
      Status="Complete">
            <ERROR Status="0" Description="OK" />
        </Activity>
    </ActivityList>
</Root>
```

Current/Actual result:
`line` is showing as `null`

Comment: Try to add an "Accept: */*" header to test out if the server is limiting the response based on http header criteria

Comment: I tried adding the accept header, but unfortunately, my `line` is still null.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want xml to come back from the server, it is likely that you need to add an "accept" header to the request to tell the server that you (the client) will "accept" xml. From your post, it appears that the default is html.

This might work for you:

```
  URL url = new URL(urlString);

  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/xml");
  conn.setDoOutput(true);

  OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
```

If you are sending xml to the server, you also may want to add a "content-type" header, like this:

```
  conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/xml");
```

ref: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: I tried setting both headers (accept & content-type) but I `line` is still `null`

Comment: To help you further, I would need the URL you are sending. I have tested this locally against a rest service that I have, and it works with no problem. As you know, if line is null, the server is not returning any data. Try adding this line just before you close() the reader and writer. You should be getting an http status of 200 if things are working propertly. `int response = conn.getResponseCode();`

Comment: Thank you StvnBrkdll. I was able to resolve the issue, thank you for you help. I have posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in my original code that prevented line from ever forming anything other than `null`.

the correct code is as follows:

```
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "text/html");


        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(xmlString);
        writer.flush();
        String builtResponse = "";
        String line ="";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builtResponse += line;
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
```